# How do I enlarge a TImage in Delphi when my cursor is over it?

Tags: delphi

I am using a VCL Application in Delphi. I have a TImage. I want to enlarge the TImage slightly when my cursor is over it. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways.

Personally, I'd create a new custom control specifically for the purpose, so it can be reused.

But if you need a quick version, you can simply use the control's `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` events:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := Image1.BoundsRect;
  R.Inflate(6, 6, 6, 6);
  Image1.BoundsRect := R;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R := Image1.BoundsRect;
  R.Inflate(-6, -6, -6, -6);
  Image1.BoundsRect := R;
end;
```

[image: Sample screenshot of a mouse-hover effect]

This is actually more robust than you might think. For instance, if you place the cursor above the image, so that it is enlarged, and then press Ctrl+Alt+Del and move the cursor away, you will find that the image is restored to its original size when you get back to the desktop.

Comment: It is *so* annoying that `Inflate` isn't a function.

Comment: Also don't forget that you might need to make this DPI aware.

Comment: This code is very useful. You do need to add those procedures to the corresponding event in the event handler of the object inspector.

Comment: @LiamPeffer: True. Actually, these methods are created automatically if you simply double-click these two events in the **Object Inspector**.